# Hosting a flask web app with a domain I already own

Tags: python, html, css, flask, web-hosting

I needed some information from you, since I haven't found much on the internet.

I recently bought a domain on godaddy.com and I wanted to use it to host my web app developed in Flask.

Given the price spent to buy the domain, I wanted to avoid spending money on hosting as well (if it could be avoided).

I tried with Netlify, but it doesn't allow you to host apps developed in Flask (it gives me everytime a 404 error), a pity because it would have been very convenient, since I could very easily configure the web app with my domain.

Can anyone tell me a possible free solution? I repeat, I already have the domain, I just need a hosting service.

Thanks in advance to those who will reply.

Comment: You can use pythonanywhere with a personal domain for about $5 a month. I don't think thats too much to ask for, for a reliable service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for free options, your best bets are Render.com or pythonanywhere, as has already been mentioned.

Personally I'd recommend Render as I have, like you, been looking for places to host my flask apps. I used to use Heroku which was perfect but once they removed the free tier I moved away.

It depends on the complexity of your flask app as to what will work with Render, but one I'm hosting uses their PostgreSQL without any issues. It's really simple to setup too if you have your repository on GitHub with their integrations.

I have one however that doesn't properly work but I think that's more to do with limitations on the free tier and how I've coded it to work. I also tried Netlify but it doesn't seem to like Flask or Python very much.